# how do i set the pixel value of radius in bubbleChart?

Tags: dc.js

I want to set the pixel radius of the bubbles on my bubbleChart. All bubbles will be 3px when bubbles represent companies, but 6px when they represent portfolios, and so on for a total of four categories. So the user can aggregate the data behind the bubbles at different levels, and the size of the bubbles should represent that.

Problem is I am struggling to set the radius in pixels.

```
bubbleChart.width(738)
          .height(315)
          .margins({left:40,right:30,top:15,bottom:30})
          .dimension(idDimBubble)
          .group(idGrpBubble)
          .clipPadding(10)
          .elasticY(true)
          .elasticX(true)
          //.mouseZoomable(true)
          // .elasticRadius(true)
          .renderLabel(false)
          .keyAccessor(function (p) { return p.value[selectArrays[0][1]] / p.value.name.length; })
          .valueAccessor(function (p) { return p.value[selectArrays[0][0]] / p.value.name.length; })
          .radiusValueAccessor(function (p) { return (filters[0].indexOf(window.gran)+1); })// this outputs a digit of 1,2, 3 or 4. I want that to correspond to a radius of 3,6,9,12.
          //.maxBubbleRelativeSize(0.05)
          .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100]))
          .y(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100]))
          .r(d3.scale.linear().domain([1, 4]).range([1,4]))
          .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
          .renderVerticalGridLines(true);
```

I would think the code above would output a pixel radius of between 1 and 4px. Instead, I have to maxBubbleRelativeSize to suppress the size because all four bubbles are too big. Even the smallest bubble is more like a radius of 10 not 1px.

Does anyone know how I can set the actual pixel size directly? Thanks

Comment: Did you try setting `bubbleChart.MIN_RADIUS = 1`. [I don't think it's documented](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/src/bubble-mixin.js#L18), definitely not the best interface!